# My prefix wants its lawyer, My suffix is earning fast!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix wants its lawyer,
>
> My suffix is earning fast!
>
> My infix can write you juicy checks,
>
> I am something you hate to last!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> SUSPENSION : You do not want your suspension lasting!
>  
>  SUSP : Short for suspect wanting his own lawyer
>  
>  PEN  Writes checks
>  
>  PENSION Earns money

Comment: If its in my car (shocks and springs and whatnot), then then I want it to last for a long time.